# React Native - Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require('NativeModules').UIManager.AndroidDrawerLayout.Constants')

Tags: ios, react-native

I am following the Hello World example for React Native according to the official startup guide [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). When running the actual project (untouched, no files edited) on XCode, I get the following error on the "Red Screen of Death".

`Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require('NativeModules').UIManager.AndroidDrawerLayout.Constants')`

The code is stock standard default code with nothing touched.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: Red Screen of Death]

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', () => HelloWorld);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8436

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  NavigatorIOS,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running this command in your app folder and then re-running the project:

```
npm install react-native@0.11.2 --save
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still happens. React native is now set to `"react-native": "^0.11.2"` on package.json. I cleaned the build and recompiled everything, and the same error occurs unfortunatley.